# XNA нормали для смежных вершин

Tags: 3d, xna

Имеются 2 треугольника, лежащие не в одной плоскости, представленные 4 вершинами (например VertexPositionNormalTexture). Сами треугольники задаются шестью индексами (у треугольников одна общая грань). Две вершины из четырех являются общими. Нормали, как известно, задаются для каждой вершины. А для смежных вершин получается нужно по 2 нормали (требуется, чтобы между треугольниками была четкая грань). Как в этом случае задать для некоторых вершин больше одной нормали?

Answer (score 0):

Нормаль является свойством вершины (как и ее расположение). Для получения резкой грани, вам нужны разные нормали. А значит - вам понадобится 6 вершин.

Разделяйте вершины, оставляйте им одинаковое расположение, делайте разные нормали и стройте по треугольнику на каждой тройке вершин.

Обычно все так и делают. Не переживайте за лишнюю геометрию, любой современной видеокарте, перемалывающей вершины миллионами, это не нагрузка.

Comment: Конечно, вариант отображения граней через TriangleList решает эту проблему, но я думал что раз придумали экономить вершины через индексы или через TriangleStrip то и для нормалей есть какой-то в этом случае вариант

Comment: Вы все равно можете экономить вершины, например, если у вас большая модель, в которой немного резких граней. Также разделение вершин часто бывает нужно при использовании UV карт с разрывами.